# Microsoft ergonomic wired keyboard 4000 - the 5 pin USB point is damaged

Tags: usb, keyboard

The keyboard is otherwise perfect, so its a shame if i have to throw it away just because the USB pin head is damaged. Is there anything i can do ?

I have been able to disassemble the keyboard.

[image: Keyboard disassembled]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a pretty standard 5-pin USB header cable. Search "usb 2 to usb 5 pin header cable" & you'll end up with something like this…

[Amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/male-Female-header-motherboard-cable/dp/B01JS8AAR2)

[image]

I'm pretty sure that even though your header is a shorter locking version, the basic plug shape is interchangeable, it just won't have the lock. At worst, tie a knot or use a cable tie just inside the exit hole as strain relief.

<sup>If I'm wrong about the header plugs being interchangeable, someone is likely to leave a comment to that effect inside an hour;)</sup>